# Migrating Access Saved Import Specifications to SSIS Package

Tags: ssis, ms-access, etl

We currently receive a multi-hundred column flat file from a vendor, and the tech prior to me had created an import specification in Microsoft Access to automatically split the file into the right fields based on field length, properly formatting dates and such, etc etc.

As I'm migrating this data to SQL Server, is there any quick way to migrate the stored import specifications from Access to a SSIS package without completely recreating it? Since it's a file based on field length rather than a CSV, it's quite a process to recreate from scratch due to the file size, so figured I'd check if anyone is familiar with an automated way.

Comment: The Import Specifications should be stored in the hidden system tables called `MSysImexSpecs` and `MSysImexColumns`